# Number of branches between two layers of the Young's lattice

Tags: nt.number-theory, sequences-and-series, partitions, young-tableaux

In the [Young's lattice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young%27s_lattice), the number of branches that connect the $N$'th layer to the $N+1$'th layer has the sequence:
$$
1,2, 4, 7, 12, 19, 30, 45, 67, 97, 139, \cdots
$$
Looking this up on OEIS, leads to [this result](https://oeis.org/A000070). This is nothing but the cumulative sum of integer partitions
$$ \sum_{k=0}^N p(k)
$$
My question is: why do we expect this number to count the number of branches between two layers of the Young's lattice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Contra what I originally thought, I’m not sure this is a general fact for all differential posets.

Nonetheless in the case of Young’s lattice it is easy to see this directly from the fact that if an element has $x$ edges coming in from below, it has $x+1$ going out above: we can always add a box in one more position than we can take away a box, in any Young diagram.

Comment: Just to clarify, by "edges" you mean "branches"? I am not even sure what's the correct terminology here.

Comment: Yes, edges of the Hasse diagram = cover relations in the poset. In other words, places you can add or remove a box.

Comment: Great! So, just to spell things out: since the number of incoming edges from the layer below is one lesser than the number of outgoing branches to the layer above, we have the recurrence relation $B(N+1)=B(N)+p(N)$ with the seed condition $B(0)=1$. And the solution to this is $B(N+1)=\sum_{n=0}^{N}p(n)$. Agree?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: This is indeed true for any 1-differential poset (where $p(k)$ is replaced by the number of elements of rank $k$). Take the coefficient of $x$ in Theorem 3.21.11 of *Enumerative Combinatorics*, vol.1, second edition. For $r$-differential posets we get an extra factor of $r$.

Comment: For another proof see the solution to Exercise 1.71 in EC1.

Comment: @RichardStanley: Thank you, Richard, for that addendum!

Comment: Thanks Sam and Richard! Is anything known about the asymptotics of this sequence?

Comment: Integrating the Hardy-Ramanujan formula gives approximately: $\frac{ e^{\pi \sqrt{2n/3}}  }{ 2\pi \sqrt{2n}   }$.